# Using shell to compute averages for students

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I have a file called: 'winter' witch contains on each line a student name and the average of his grades on his winter finals:

```
John 4
Brian 8.5
```

Another file called: 'summer' contains on each line a student name and 5 grades on his summer finals:

```
John 8 7 9 4 7
Brian 10 9 4 5 8
```

I want to compute the annual average grade for each student:

```
John ((8+7+9+4+7)/5 + 4)/2
Brian ((10+9+4+5+8)/5 + 8.5)/2
```

The output will be sorted by the annual average, so the student with the highest grade comes first.

I want this to be done using shell programming.

I've tried computing the average using awk:

```
awk '{print $1 " " ($2 + $3 + $4 + $5 + $6)/5}' summer
```

But I have no idea how to continue, or even how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $1,(a[$1]+($2+$3+$4+$5+$6)/5)/2}' winter summer | sort -rnk2
Brian 7.85
John 5.5
```

**Explanation:**

The condition `FNR==NR` is only true when we are in the first file `winter` so the block is only executed for that file. The block simply creates an array where the student names are the keys and the grades are the values. The `next` statement jumps to the next line in file. When we are in the second file the script is much the same as yours but we use the array to get the grade from the first file. The sort is simple `-r` reverse `-n` numerical sort on the second field `-k2`.

It should be noted that this script assumes no two students have the same name.